# Pyodbc Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

Tags: sql-server, pyodbc

I installed the driver and verified it using `pyodbc.drivers()`.

```
import pyodbc
print(pyodbc.drivers())

['PostgreSQL', 'MySQL', 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server']

# Connect 

connection = pyodbc.connect(
                              'Driver={SQL Server};'
                              'Server=xxx;'
                              'Database=Kxxxx;'
                              'Trusted_Connection=True;'
                           )
```

I get an error:

```
Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

Comment: Aside... `ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server` is quite old and cannot be used to connect to SQL Server 2017, 2019 nor 2022, nor any of the Azure SQL types.

Comment: Since you have `ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server` installed have you considered trying `Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};` instead of `Driver={SQL Server};`?